# tokenHandler() doesn't fire when you open app (ios, PushPlugin), have to minimize the app then reopen it to fire event

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, push-notification

I'm trying to implement the new PhoneGap PushPlugin for iOS but can't figure out why I'm having this issue.

When the app loads, it successfully calls the OnDeviceReadyPush function:

```
var pushNotification;

function onDeviceReadyPush() {
$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, { "senderID":     "661780372179", "ecb": "onNotificationGCM" });
} else {
    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, { "badge": "true", "sound":     "true", "alert": "true", "ecb": "onNotificationAPN" });
}
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReadyPush, true);
```

Which is suppose to kick of the tokenHandler function:

```
function tokenHandler(result) {
$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: ' + result + '</li>');
// Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
// here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.

$.get("", { "deviceid": result}, processResult);

function processResult(data, textStatus) {
    alert(data);
}
}
```

It doesn't work until I minimize the app and then come back into it. It then fires the tokenHandler event.

Please help, I've been looking at this trying everything I can think of for two days now and am going crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong cordova file. After updating everything to the newest at the time, it started working as expected.

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? I have the same issue. Just upgraded to Cordova 3.1.0-0.2.0, and updated the PushPlugin as well, now iOS does not call the token handler function, but the equivalent Android one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

`document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReadyPush, FALSE);`

Comment: Thanks for your input, I did try that but it still didn't work. I ended up updated everything to the newest version and it started working as expected. I think I was using the wrong cordova file.